# curl callback in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, libcurl

I have a callback function for CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION in codeigniter like below:

```
class download_model extends CI_Model {
function downloadIt($link){

  $targetFile = FCPATH."upload/".basename($link);
  $handle = fopen($targetFile, 'w');

   $ch = curl_init( $link );
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false );
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'progressCallback' );
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $handle );
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 2 );
   curl_exec( $ch );
   curl_close($ch);
}

function progressCallback( $params )
{
// params here
}

}
```

but i get below error using above code:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: curl_exec() [function.curl-exec]: Cannot call the
>   CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION

And if i move that function progressCallback() to root index.php it works properly, what would be efficient  way to add this function in codeigniter so curl callback will recognize it?
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to add callback function for native PHP functions in Codeigniter.

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, array('name_of_controller', 'name_of_function' );
```

This is how I do it when I use functions like usort();

Comment: That's OK, glad to save you a headache. I remember it took me ages to work that out.